# PanoTools Scripting

Tags: panorama, image-stitching

I have a series of microscope images that I'm trying to stitch together.

In all cases the images are made by horizontally shifting the stage.  [Autostitch](http://matthewalunbrown.com/autostitch/autostitch.html) does an absolutely wonderful job.  Unfortunately, Autostitch is not scriptable, only outputs JPGs, and it's probably wrong to use a Cylindrical projection in my application.

I have been trying to match Autostitch's result using PanoTools and autopano-sift-c (the same algorithm as Autostitch).  I've tried following the scripting instructions at https://wiki.panotools.org/Panorama_scripting_in_a_nutshell but I can barely get an image out, let alone anything that's close to correct.

here's my script so far ...

```
#! /bin/sh

pto_gen *.tif -o project.pto
autopano-sift-c --projection 0,50 -o project.pto project.pto
autooptimiser -a -l -s -o project.pto project.pto
pano_modify  --projection=0 --fov=AUTO --center --canvas=100% --output-type=NORMAL --output-exposure=0 --ldr-file=PNG -o project.pto project.pto
hugin_executor --stitching --prefix=pano project.pto
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.